# Disk Size Of Schema PostgreSQL on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have multitenant app rails and tried for to get size disk of schema posgresql per account. Initially, I tried it at the views, roughly like this :

```
<% for account in @accounts %>
<td>
    <%= number_to_human_size(@schemasize = (ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(%q{select sum(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name)) from information_schema.tables where table_schema in ('} +account.schema+ %q{') group by table_schema}).to_s.gsub(/\D/, '').to_f + account.size_logo.to_f), :locale=> 'en') %>
</td>
<% end %>
```

Output on browser

```
| schema  | usage  |
|_________|________|
| schema1 | 259 KB |
| schema2 | 294 KB |
```

But **it isn't insert into database** (on public schema). **Now, I want it store in database.**

Here's controller for handle size disk of schema per account :

```
@accounts.each do |t|
     select_size = "select sum(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name)) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = " + t.schema.to_s + " group by table_schema"
     @a =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(select_size)  
     @b = @a.to_s.gsub(/\D/, '').to_f
     @c = t.size_logo.to_f
     @d = @b + @c
     @cek_schema = Usage.find_by_account_id(t.id)
     if @cek_schema.nil?
       Usage.create(:account_id => t.id, :size => @d)
     else
       @cek_schema.destroy
       Usage.create(:account_id => t.id, :size => @d)
     end
end
```

I get an error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in AccountsController#kapasitas

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "schema1" does not exist
LINE 1: ... from information_schema.tables where table_schema = schema1
                                                                ^
: select sum(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name)) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = schema1 group by table_schema
```

Can anyone tell me what the mistake?

- get size disk of schema and store in database

Help me.

Thanks

Comment: t.schema.to_s isn't quoted. Pg thinks it's a table name. Use a ? placeholder or put single quotes around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DondiMichaelStroma

t.schema.to_s isn't quoted. Pg thinks it's a table name.

**Solution :** put single quotes around t.schema.to_s

```
select_size = "select sum(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name)) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = '" + t.schema.to_s + "' group by table_schema"
```